# Parameters for numpy.random.lognormal function

Tags: numpy, statistics

I need to create a fictitious log-normal distribution of household income in a particular area. The data I have are: Average: 13,600 and Standard Deviation 7,900.

What should be the parameters in the function numpy.random.lognormal?
When i set the mean and the standard deviation as they are most of the values in the distribution are "inf", and the values also doesn't make sense when i set the parameters as the log of the mean and standard deviation.

If someone can help me to figure out what the parameters are it would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a nontrivial task as the moments of the log-normal distribution should be solved for the unknown parameters. By looking at say [Wikipedia][1], you will find the mean and variance of the log-normal distribution to be exp(mu + sigma**2) and [exp(sigma**2)-1]*exp(2*mu+sigma**2), respectively.

The choice of mu and sigma should solve exp(mu + sigma**2) = 13600 and [exp(sigma**2)-1]*exp(2*mu+sigma**2)= 7900**2. This can be solved analytically because the first equation squared provides exactly exp(2*mu+sigma**2) thus eliminating the variable mu from the second equation.

A sample code is provided below. I took a large sample size to explicitly show that the mean and standard deviation of the simulated data are close to the desired numbers.

```
import numpy as np

# Input characteristics
DataAverage = 13600
DataStdDev = 7900

# Sample size
SampleSize = 100000

# Mean and variance of the standard lognormal distribution
SigmaLogNormal = np.sqrt( np.log(1+(DataStdDev/DataAverage)**2))
MeanLogNormal = np.log( DataAverage ) - SigmaLogNormal**2/2
print(MeanLogNormal, SigmaLogNormal)

# Obtain draw from log-normal distribution
Draw = np.random.lognormal(mean=MeanLogNormal, sigma=SigmaLogNormal, size=SampleSize)

# Check
print( np.mean(Draw), np.std(Draw))
```

Comment: Thanks! shuold I set the output as the parameters in the function as they are? becouse if I do most of the values are still "inf"

Comment: I ment, after I run this code and get the output: np.mean(SimulatedDraw), np.std(SimulatedDraw), how can I get the distribution itself? 

I understand the output from the code you wrote is the average and the average standard deviation, how do I generate a distribution from them?

Comment: I don't think this is right -- the shape will be the shape of a lognormal(0, 1) distribution, and that's probably not the shape that fits income distributions. A better way is to solve the equations for mean and variance for the parameters mu and sigma, and use those to generate the sample.

Comment: Yes, the mean and variance come out right, but the shape is wrong. Note that the way you've defined it, the least possible value is greater than zero (it's actually 7600 + something given the code you posted), while for a lognormal distribution, values all the way down to zero have nonzero probability.

Comment: For the record, I get mu = 9.34 and sigma = sqrt(0.2546), assuming mean = 13000 and sd = 7000, using the formulas for mean and variance on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @RobertDodier You are right! Thanks for spotting this. Let me update the code accordingly.